# When building an index of items, how to show which a user has liked/starred

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails 4/5, I'm trying to show a list of items, and if the searching user has liked or saved any of these items, then to display that somewhere on my index. This is similar to social networks showing a feed of posts and allowing me to see whether I've already liked the post, or showing a list of items and marking whether I've saved any of the items on the list.

For a simple example, imagine that I have a `User`, a `Post`, and a `LikedPost` join model. Users can create posts, and then other users can like those posts. As a user, I can look through posts and also see if I've liked one of those posts.

In theory, something like this should work:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:liked_posts)
             .where('liked_posts.user_id = ?', current_user.id)
             .references(:liked_posts)
```

But that actually performs a query that **only** shows me posts which I've liked. Other posts are filtered out.

I'm having a strangely hard time finding anything relevant online, and what I am able to find basically comes down to 'you'll need to write the SQL.' Any tips/advice?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so on your index page you have a list of posts right? and for each post... you display the name or something? why not have something like:

```
<%= image_tag 'heart.png' if post.liked_by?(current_user) %>
```

on the page next to the name then in the post model something like

```
 def liked_by?(user)
    self.liked_posts.where(:user_id => user.id).exists?
 end
```

(Note: not checked for typos and minor bugs)

Comment: Thanks! That seems pretty straightforward, but I believe it causes an n+1 query issue. With lower traffic, that may be a fine trade-off.

Comment: yeah for sure it'll increase the queries - but this is a "do it first and see if it creates a bottleneck, then optimise it later if it does" situation :D

Comment: Thanks -- that's definitely the right approach, of course! I wound up thinking through a way to solve this problem with minimal database queries, but it's a too-complicated controller action. I appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've thought through another solution that would work, so I'm posting here in case anyone stumbles upon this in the future, though this solution doesn't feel very 'rails-y' and clutters my controller.

Anyways, my index would look something like this:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all # in reality, paginated or limited
  these_posts = []
  @posts.each do |post|
    these_posts << post.id
  end

  @liked_posts = LikedPost.where(user_id: current_user)
                          .where(post_id: these_posts)

  @liked_posts_hash = Hash.new(false)
  @liked_posts.each do |liked_post|
    @liked_posts_hash[liked_post.post_id] = true
  end

  @posts.each do |post|
    post.liked = @liked_posts_hash[post.id] #liked is an attr_accessor
  end
end
```

So, that's a ton of extra complexity compared to Taryn's much cleaner response. But (at the expense of running through your posts array twice and your liked_posts array once) it does limit the database queries to two instead of n+1.

Looking through the response time, in my development machine, building the view this way for 20 posts is taking me about 100ms versus 130ms for the per-object query, so about 25% faster but neither approach is particularly slow on a development database with few actual records.

I'd appreciate thoughts on cleaning this up, as well.